# C++ displaying HTML code as a website (CGI Program)

Tags: c++, cgi

I hope I explain this right.. but I need my C++ program to display an HTML website. The code that I have right now only displays the text. How do I make it so it is actually displayed like a website (using HTML code)? I am going to use the .exe file uploaded to a server to display the page.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
    cout << "<h2>My first CGI program</h2>\n";
    cout << "<h1>This is a test</h1>\n";
    cout << "<h3>Why is this not working</h3>\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is that chapter I never got to. Looks like you need to do a GET request and pass the file path.

Comment: There's a lot more to it than this. Your program needs to support an interface like CGI or FastCGI. You then need some server software (like Apache, nginx, etc.) to forward incoming HTTP requests to your program. Then your program should process the HTTP request and respond with a valid HTTP response. Do you have a web server set up?

Comment: @sftrabbit yes, I have Apache set up. I have it working so it displays the page, but just as text. So the <h1> etc is doing nothing, it just shows up as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTTP response needs the status line, and you should change the mime type to `text/html`:

```
cout << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n";
cout << "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
cout << "<h2>My first CGI program</h2>\n";
cout << "<h1>This is a test</h1>\n";
cout << "<h3>Why is this not working</h3>\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I had to get rid of the first line cout << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n";  for some reason. Any idea how to get background/font colors to work? This gives me an error cout << "<BODY BGCOLOR="#ff6600">";

Comment: `"<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#ff6600\">"`